# How to briefly declare multiple byte arrays in c#

Tags: c#, byte, declare

For example, I want to declare the following content but wish to have a simple way. And later use each of them separately:

```
$byte[] image_bt_update_1 = null;
$byte[] image_bt_update_2 = null;
$byte[] image_bt_update_3 = null;
$byte[] image_bt_update_4 = null;
```

Comment: `$byte []` is not valid c# code - `$byte`isn't a valid type.

Comment: There's no need to "initialize" them with `null`. If you just write `byte[] someArray;`, `null` is already the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# you can use array of array

```
byte[][] image_tb_update = new byte[4][_N];
```

where _N is dimension of your **image_tb_update** array

and refer it as

```
image_tb_update[0][0]... image_tb_update[0][_N-1]
image_tb_update[3][0]... image_tb_update[3][_N-1]
```

to initialize all elemet

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
   for (int j=0;i<_N;j++)
      image_tb_update[i][j]=0;
```

Answer (score -1):

As they are the same type, you could replace them with:

`$byte[] image_bt_update_1 = null, image_bt_update_2 = null, image_bt_update_3 = null, image_bt_update_4 = null;`